# Input parameter passing: is there a size threshold for efficient pass-by-value?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

In C++, when an input argument is *cheap to copy* (e.g. like an `int`, `float`, etc.), it's usually passed simply *by value*. Instead, input "observed" arguments that aren't cheap to copy (e.g. `std::string`) are passed by `const &`.

I was wondering about types like a POD representing a 2D vector having `int` coordinates, e.g.

```
struct Vec2i
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};
```

On 32-bit MSVC compiler, it's just 8 bytes (`2 * sizeof(int)`). Would you pass it by value or by `const &`?

And what about a `Vec2d` having `double`-type coordinates?
(On MSVC it would be `2 * sizeof(double)`, so `2 * 8 = 16` bytes.)

Is there a *"size threshold"* (e.g. 16 bytes?) for putting a line and say: *"for PODs over size X pass by `const &`, and for smaller PODs pass by value"*?

---

**PS:** Please don't use arguments as "premature optimization" in replies.
This to me sounds like the case of `++it` vs. `it++` (where `it` is an STL iterator): it's not that `++it` is a premature optimization, the point is that `it++` is a *premature pessimization* :)

Comment: +1 for premature pessimization.

Comment: If you care, benchmark.  There's no universal answer across architectures.

Comment: @TonyD: I'd be interested at least in x86 and x64; ARM would be a nice addition as well.

Comment: I'd assume there's really no tangible difference for a POD as simple as the `Vec2i` you listed.

Comment: @faranwath: I thought the same, since I usually pass `double` by value, and `sizeof(Vec2i) == sizeof(double)`. Anyway, I'd be curious if there is a threshold. For example, what about `std::complex<double>` (which is basically two `double`s)?

Comment: @Mr.C64 - Wouldn't it be more of an issue if there is a user-defined copy constructor that takes a long time?  You can create a "small" class that can have an awfully slow copy constructor.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm assuming trivial memberwise copy.

Comment: @Mr.C64 You have to take what PaulMcKenzie said into account. If that's not the case, then I think the easiest thing to do would be passing non-empty user-defined types by reference, just in case. Thing is, you cannot go wrong that way.

Comment: @faranwath Sure you can. Aliasing gives optimizers a hard time.

Comment: @FredOverflow Unless you're invoking the function taking the argument by reference a billion times, I doubt that becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, one driving factor is whether it's possible to pass a variable in one or more registers. In the 20th century, compilers were doing quite well when an argument type mapped directly to a register. Passing a structure with two members in a register pair is a 21st century optimization.

As you mention x86 in your comments, that's a special case. It's register-starved, and may not have a register pair available for argument passing. Both x86 and ARM are much better in this respect, one of the reasons why x64 is often faster and ARM more power-economic

`boost::call_traits<T>` is an attempt to figure out whether it's smart to pass `T` by reference, but it's not perfect.

Comment: You may have a typo when you wrote _"Both x86 and ARM are much better..."_; maybe you meant: _"Both **x64** and ARM..."_?